# WPF: How to limit number of rows shown by ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox

Is it possible to limit the number of rows a listbox show? 
Eg. let´s say I have a ItemSource with 100 items, but I only want my listbox to be 10 items high.

Comment: Do you want your ListBox to only *contain* 10 items or for it to *fit* only 10 items, having to scroll for the rest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set height of list box
    this.listbox.Height = (this.listbox.ActualHeight / this.listbox.Items.Count) * 10;
}
```

Attach this to the `Loaded` Event of your control (otherwise `ActualHeight` is not set).

Comment: Ideally you should also subtract `listbox.BorderThickness` (top and bottom) from its `ActualHeight` - then the calculation will be precise (in my measurements).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `ListBox` to only **fit** 10 items, having to scroll for the rest, you can simply set the height of `ListBoxItem`s to be the height of the `ListBox` divided by 10.

If you want to allow the `ListBox` to resize, you will have to adjust the `ListBoxItem` height dynamically on each resize event.

Static example:

```
<ListBox Height="500">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    </Style>  
    </ListBox.Resources>

  <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Four</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Five</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Six</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Seven</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Eight</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Nine</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Ten</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Eleven</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Twelve</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Thirteen</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Fourteen</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Fifteen</ListBoxItem>
  <!-- etc. -->

</ListBox>
```